# What are the advantages of Breadth First Search over Iterative Deepening Depth First Search and vice versa?

Tags: search, tree, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

They both find the shortest path and I know BFS uses way more memory, but are there any clear advantages BFS to IDDFS and vice versa.